# expresion regular no funciona Java

Tags: java, netbeans

hola buenas gente una consulta con respecto al lenguaje java, estoy intentado crear una expresión regular que cumpla con todas estas condiciones

**Tener una longitud máxima de 20 caracteres.
Es sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas.
Empezar con una letra.
Tener solo letras y números.
No usar caracteres especiales.**

estoy creándola aun, pero tengo esto

archivo es el nombre de un string que debe cumplir como nombre con dichas características.

pero nose como combinar todo en la misma expresión regular

```
if(archivo.matches("[a-zA-Z][_{1}a-zA-Z0-9]*[^_]\\.LID")){
                
                System.out.println("El archivo presenta lleva un nombre valido");
                
            }else{
                System.out.println("El nombre del archivo es invalido");
            }
```

nose como incluir que ser una extension de 20 caracteres como máximo.
no usar caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proba usando la siguiente expresion regular:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mystring = "zasdasd123123__";
    if(mystring.matches("(\\s|^)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,19}\\b")) System.out.println("Patron encontrado");
    else System.out.println("Patron no encontrado");
  }
}
```

Descomponiendo:

```
(\\s|^) el patron comenzara con un meta carácter de espacio \s (salto de línea, tabulación, espacio, retorno de carro etc.) o comenzara al principio de la línea (^)
[A-Za-z] Luego tendrá un solo carácter letra mayúscula o minúscula, el {1} que puse antes no era necesario
[A-Za-z0-9]{0,19} Luego tendrá una serie de caracteres alfanuméricos con una longitud mínima de 0 y máxima de 19
\\b el meta carácter \\b significa 'fin de cadena alfanumérica'
```

Comment: gracias, te molestaría explicarme un poco que significa las nuevas cosas que le agregaste como (\\s|^) como las demás cosas, es que estas expresiones son difíciles de leer, entonces como para apuntarlo jeje

Comment: @EstherPorta claro, ahí edito mi respuesta.

Comment: @EstherPorta si copias y pegas la expresión regular en un sitio como regex101 en la parte derecha de la web puedes ver una vista detallada de lo que hace cada parte de la expresión. Ayuda mucho porque puedes ir modificándola y viendo lo que hace cada cambio en tiempo real, además de poder poner datos de prueba y ver qué captura y qué no.

Comment: oi enserio que loco no sabía de eso muchas gracias de verdad

Answer (score 2):

```
if(archivo.matches("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,20}$")){            
    System.out.println("El archivo presenta lleva un nombre valido");
            
} else {
    System.out.println("El nombre del archivo es invalido");
}
```

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda ser correcta le hace falta explicar el motivo por el cual es una solución válida. Por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega detalles y una explicación.